# How can I colour web page differently?

Tags: html, css, background

HI. What i Want to do is i want to color up my homepage with 2 colors, where the centre[image] of the page is different color with the whole's background color. So, the blue gridlines is the part where i want it in white color.

below is the code:

```html
    <body>
    <style>
    body {
    
    background-color: #A2D8EB;
    }
    #wrapper 
    {
    
    background-color:#F4F4F4;
    
    }
    
     
    </style>
    <center>
    <br>
    <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
       <li class='active'><a href='index.html'>Utama</a></li>
       <li><a href='login design.php'>Log Masuk</a></li>
       <li><a href='contact.php'>Hubungi Kami</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </center>
    <center>
    <br><br>
    
    <img src="bilik/a.gif">
    
    </center>
    <center>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <p font face="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica size="6" color="black">Sistem ini dibangunkan oleh Cawangan Teknologi Maklumat </p>
    <p font face="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica size="6" color="black"> Jabatan Kastam Diraja Malaysia Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur </p>
    <p font face="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica size="6" color="black">bagi memudahkan semua staf untuk membuat tempahan bilik di JKDM WPKL  </p>
    </div>
    </center>
    </body>
```

so i really hope you guys can help me out. thank you :

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have understood your problem and here is the solution of it. Try it may be this is what you wanted.

```html
               <body>
    <style>
    body {
    
    background-color: #A2D8EB;
    }
    #wrapper 
    {
    
    background-color:#F4F4F4;
    width: 60%;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    }
    
     
    </style>
    <div style="text-align: -webkit-center;">
    <br>
    <div id="cssmenu">
    <ul >
       <li class='active'><a href='index.html'>Utama</a></li>
       <li><a href='login design.php'>Log Masuk</a></li>
       <li><a href='contact.php'>Hubungi Kami</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: -webkit-center;">
    <div id="wrapper" >
    <div style="text-align: -webkit-center;">
    <br><br>
    
    <img src="bilik/a.gif">
    
   </div>
    <div style="text-align: -webkit-center;">
    <div >
    <p font face="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica" size="6" color="black">Sistem ini dibangunkan oleh Cawangan Teknologi Maklumat 
    </p>
    <p font face="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica" size="6" color="black"> Jabatan Kastam Diraja Malaysia Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur </p>
    <p font face="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica" size="6" color="black">bagi memudahkan semua staf untuk membuat tempahan bilik di JKDM WPKL  </p>
    </div>
    </div></div></div>
    </body>
```

Hope this may help you.

[html](/questions/tagged/html) [css](/questions/tagged/css) [background](/questions/tagged/background)

Comment: There is one problem. The `<center>` tag is no longer supported in HTML5

Comment: thanks for highlighting @Dragonthoughts... Now it is fine